# Making an app with Tabs

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make and app that loads `WebViews` when tapping on each tab.
But instead of doing that its randomly loading the webs before tapping any tab and its going full screen. Here is my code:

**Main Activity.java**

```
package com.grancanariaboattrips.myapplication;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TableLayout;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

private SectionsPageAdapter mSectionsPageAdapter;

private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: Starting");


    mSectionsPageAdapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    setupViewPager(mViewPager);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);



}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager){

    SectionsPageAdapter adapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new Fragment1(),"Google");
    adapter.addFragment(new Fragment2(),"Spotify");
    adapter.addFragment(new Fragment3(),"Youtube");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

}

}
```

**Fragment1.java (another 2 same code changing names and url)**

```
package com.grancanariaboattrips.myapplication;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class Fragment1 extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "Fragment1";


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fragment1, container, false);
    WebView webView=(WebView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.Web);
    webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com");
    return rootView;
}

}
```

**SectionsPageAdapter.java**

```
package com.grancanariaboattrips.myapplication;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;




public class SectionsPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
private final List<String> mFragmentTittleList = new ArrayList<>();


public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title){
    mFragmentList.add(fragment);
    mFragmentTittleList.add(title);
}


public SectionsPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position){
    return mFragmentTittleList.get(position);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return mFragmentList.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mFragmentList.size();
}


}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.grancanariaboattrips.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**activity_fragment.xml (there is another 2 as well)**

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context="com.grancanariaboattrips.myapplication.Fragment1">

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/Web">

    </WebView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**menu_main.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.grancanariaboattrips.myapplication.MainActivity">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
```

Comment: if this is a sample project, can you upload it on Dropbox and share a link. It helps us to identify the problem easily.

Comment: Here is the project link to download: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3rs06i09yrjqw2e/MyApplication.zip?dl=0